# rails built in datetime validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Does rails do any validation for datetime?  I found a plugin 
http://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/tree/master, 
but it seems like something that should come in out of the box.

Comment: I love `validates_timeliness`.  It can be installed as a gem.  It was about as fast to install as copy-and-pasting the selected answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There's no built-in ActiveRecord validator for DateTimes, but you can easily add this sort of capability to an ActiveRecord model, without using a plugin, with something like this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :happened_at_is_valid_datetime

  def happened_at_is_valid_datetime
    errors.add(:happened_at, 'must be a valid datetime') if ((DateTime.parse(happened_at) rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm glad this helped.  It's not the most glorious code, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Tried `validates_timeliness` but had issues using getters and setters. This worked perfectly.

Comment: Why not:  `DateTime.parse(happened_at) rescue errors.add(:happened_at, 'must be a valid datetime')` ? Rescue to ArgumentError just to check if it's an ArgumentError makes not much sense for me.

Comment: won't it normally be typecast according to the column of the database? Isn't this unnecessary?

Comment: If you get this `no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String` try `to_s` on the `DateTime.parse(happened_at.to_s)`

Comment: Another one to check if `happened_at` is after a given `DateTime`:
`elsif (((DateTime.now + 59.mins >= DateTime.parse(happened_at))
rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError)`

Answer (score 14):

Gabe's answer didn't work for me, so here's what I did to validate my dates:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :mydate_is_date?

  private

  def mydate_is_date?
    if !mydate.is_a?(Date)
      errors.add(:mydate, 'must be a valid date') 
    end
  end
end
```

I was just looking to validate that the date is in fact a date, and not a string, character, int, float, etc...

More complex date validation can be found here: https://github.com/codegram/date_validator

Comment: The gem is the most easy solution, took me three minutes to implement. Not worth it writing any code.

Comment: @MichaelSchmitz - It is worth writing code because the code is self explanatory - new people looking at the code might not know of that gems existence and it adds extra overhead for what is a simple task.

Comment: @Toby - thanks for the pointer, you are right about that. I am the only developer for now, guess I was just happy that it worked.

Comment: This just validates the object being an instance of a date, but it can be nil, or even with an invalid date.

Comment: And the gem its not overhead, because otherwise you will have to rewrite your method in every model.

Comment: @Marcelo `nil.is_a?(Date)` is false. `nil.class` is NilClass.

Answer (score 10):

Recent versions of Rails will [type cast](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Accessing+attributes+before+they+have+been+typecasted) values before validation, so invalid values will be passed as `nil`s to custom validators. I'm doing something like this:

```rb
# app/validators/date_time_validator.rb
class DateTimeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if record.public_send("#{attribute}_before_type_cast").present? && value.blank?
      record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid)
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/something.rb
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :sold_at, date_time: true
end
```

```rb
# spec/models/something_spec.rb (using factory_girl and RSpec)
describe Something do
  subject { build(:something) }

  it 'should validate that :sold_at is datetimey' do
    is_expected.not_to allow_value(0, '0', 'lorem').for(:sold_at).with_message(:invalid)
    is_expected.to allow_value(Time.current.iso8601).for(:sold_at)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom datetime validator by yourself

1) create a folder called validators in inside app directory

2) create a file datetime_validator.rb. with the following content inside app/validators directory

```
 class DatetimeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if ((DateTime.parse(value) rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError)  
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "must be a valid datetime")
    end
  end
end
```

3) Apply this validation on model

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :happend_at, datetime: true
end
```

4) Add the below line in application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/app/validators/"]
```

5) Restart your rails application

Note: The above method tested in rails 4

Comment: Personally I'd make it `DateTimeValidator` (capital T) because it's `DateTime` you're validating. Makes more sense from a `constantize` point of view.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a gem `date_validator`. See https://rubygems.org/gems/date_validator. It is well maintained and its API is simple and compact.

Comment: Note for anyone arriving here, years had passed... This gem doesn't validate dates backed as strings in db: https://github.com/codegram/date_validator/issues/38 and is loosley mantained (see PR's pending)

Answer (score -3):

It's quite necessary to validate dates. With the default Rails form helpers you could select dates like September 31st.

Comment: Validating user input through forms is a good start, but the context of the question suggests that the OP was asking about Rails model validations.