# Datetime field saves nil value when saving a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, datetime

I have a problem with Datetime field in my Rails app. I have a validation that should accept valid Datetime, and allows null or blank values (code is from my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068820/same-custom-validation-for-several-fields-in-railstrue) yesterday):

```
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  class DateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record,attribute,value)
      record.errors[attribute] << "must be a valid datetime" unless ((DateTime.parse(value) rescue nil))
    end
  end
  validates :datetime_field :date => true, :allow_nil => true, :allow_blank => true
```

However, when set datetime_field to some string, my model overrides the previous value of datetime_field and sets it to nil (in rails console I get the following:

```
object.update_attributes("datetime_field" => "Now")
true
object.datetime_field.nil?
true
```

How to stop setting my datetime field to nil after updating with string, and at the same time keep being able to blank this field explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You validations are strange: datetime_field should be a date and at the same time it can be nil or blank. But nil or blank can't be date. So your validation should sounds like: `datetime_field should be DATE or BLANK or NIL`:

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
class DateOrBlankValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record,attribute,value)
    record.errors[attribute] << "must be a valid datetime or blank" unless value.blank? or ((DateTime.parse(value) rescue nil))
  end
end
validates :datetime_field :date_or_blank => true
```

**UPD**

Just for notice. `nil.blank? => true`. So you never need to validate something if it is `nil` if you are checking if it is `blank?`. `Blank?` will return true for empty objects and for nil objects: `"".blank? => true`, `nil.blank? => true`

Answer (score 0):

Is your datetime_field marked as datetime in your migration?

If so datetime_field is being set to nil becouse string you've passed isn't valid datetime string. Try doing this instead:

```
object.update_attributes("datetime_field" => "2010-01-01")
true
```

Is suppose then

```
object.datetime_field
```

should return

```
2010-01-01
```