# Rails 4.0 Custom Validator Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, customvalidator

I am attempting to validate some dates in a Rails 4 application and it's not working.

I looked at lots of similar code samples, like this [Same custom validation for several fields in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068820/same-custom-validation-for-several-fields-in-rails) and this http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3. (And others more complicated). I don't understand why my example doesn't work. Trying to find the problem, I've stripped out the actual validation code, and left a stub, because the validation doesn't seem to run and that would seem the base problem (or at least, the first problem).

Here's the code in the validator (which is in app/validators/custom_date_validator.rb

```
class CustomDateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    puts "Custom validator was called"
    record.errors[attribute] << "Date Not Valid" unless false
  end
end
```

Here's the code from the model:

```
class CaseInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
    validates :started, :custom_date => true
```

The error message is:

```
argument out of range
Extracted source (around line #104): 
respond_to do |format|
104 if ( @case_information.update_attributes(params[:case_information]) && @case_information.update_attributes(params[:law_guardians]) )
format.html { redirect_to @case_information, notice: 'Case information was successfully updated.' }
format.json { head :no_content }
```

The error is (I think) intentional, I put in a date of "1/123/2012", but the validator isn't catching it. Well, actually I stripped out all the validation code and have (I think) the validator writing to the log, as it doesn't seem the validator is even running, at least, there's nothing in the log that shows it ran.

I know that the validator code is being found because in the model, if I change the validation name even a bit I get an error that the validation can't be found.

Really stupid noob question I am sure, your patience is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's indeed failing before your validator gets run-- the "argument out of range" error is what happens when you call `Time.parse` on a date that can't exist. In irb:

```
2.0.0p247 :004 > require 'time'
=> true
2.0.0p247 :005 > Time.parse("1/123/2012")
ArgumentError: argument out of range
```

And I'm betting that `started` is a `datetime` or `timestamp` attribute, right? Rails tries to convert the string from the `params` hash to their types *before* any validations are run.

Comment: Thanks Carol, haven't check yet, but what you say seems very much spot on. I guess I have to do some more research to accomplish the validation. Maybe take in the value not as the attribute it is, but just as string, and see if I can parse that? Seems awkward. Is there an easier way? Is the switch to Rails 4 the issue? Seems like there were good date validators in Rails 3, but less so in Rails 4?

Comment: What is the problem that you're really trying to solve? If you're trying to prevent someone from entering an invalid date, isn't the type conversion doing that? Do you want to LET people enter things like "1/123/2012"? If you do, is it really a date that you want to use for that attribute's type then?

Comment: Thanks Carol. I tried to vote up your comments, but I don't have the rep to do so. Anyway, all I'm trying to do is validate a datetime in Rails 4, and I must be missing something, because it doesn't seem straight-forward at all. I can't seem to catch the exception that the type conversion causes, it's gone before my validator kicks in. Do I trap around the edit action in the controller?

Comment: I've looked at this repeatedly, and I cannot make it work. My noob skilz are insufficient. That said, I think the real problem is the one described here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11867

Comment: Apparently the bug is being worked on (see link), but I have to be missing something, because to get a date validation that catches "2/31/2014" in Rails 4, I had to resort to javascript. What am I missing?