# Validate Datetime in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to validate two date fields. I want to validate that the second field is always the same date or any date after the first one.

Example if date1 is 22/05/2011 date2 can not be 20/05/2011.

I am using ruby on rails 3.0.7, and I am trying to do this at the model level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See that post: [Rails 3 Datetime validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370926/rails-built-in-datetime-validation)

and also:

[Rails 3 custom validation between datetime](http://kav1nsky.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/rails-3-custom-validation-between-datetime-type/)
:)

Answer (score 3):

a.) there's an app for that

```
gem "validates_date_time", :git => "git://github.com/sofatutor/validates_date_time", :branch => 'rails-3'
```

b.) I'm actually not using that gem because I found this handy model method before the gem

```
class KeyPerson < ActiveRecord::Base

validate :started_at_is_date?

private

def started_at_is_date?
   if !started_at.is_a?(Date)
     errors.add(:started_at, 'must be a valid date') 
   end
  end
  end
```

where `:started_at` is the column's name. That's a little bit of ruby magic/chaos for you with the dynamic method name handling thing