# How can I change the end_date from date filter in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want the start_date to be prior to the end_date or make a validation for the end_date to be <= Date.today.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?   A straightforward check to see if date1 is >= date2 should be sufficient.

Comment: I tried some validations and custom methods in the model but they didn't work.The problem is I don't know where to implement that condition.In the model or inside ActiveAdmin?

Comment: You would do it in the model.  Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1371350/643500 or look at date_validator https://github.com/codegram/date_validator  The condition will be checked before object save

Comment: This date validation is for a search from Active Admin so it doesn't really help that the condition is checked before save.