# Rails Datetime accepting incorrect values despite of the validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

db/migrate/20160222115940_create_menus.rb

```
class CreateMenus < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :menus do |t|
      t.datetime :menu_date

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/menu.rb

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :menu_date, format: {
    with: /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})?/,
    message: "only correct date formats are allowed"
  }

end
```

I even tested the regex properly here :- http://rubular.com/r/A8r8AGWgHv

Still you can see it's accepting wrong format in the terminal output.

[image]

Comment: You should consider using a date or datetime column together with the [date input helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers).

Comment: i m already using datetime column, i added that also in the question now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370926/rails-built-in-datetime-validation

Comment: $> DateTime.parse("xyz 123")
=> Mon, 02 May 2016 00:00:00 +0000. DateTime successfully parses the above testcase. That's the issue. But i don't know why the regex being effective here.

Comment: can anyone answer this ?