# How to get correct date of entry with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My model file

```
*class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:confirmable
   validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 40}  
   validates :phone_number, presence: true, length: {maximum: 12} validates_date :date_of_birth, :before => lambda { 18.years.ago },
                               :before_message => "must be at least 18 years old"
end*
```

My Html file

```
<%= f.label :date_of_birth %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, order: [:day, :month, :year], :start_year=>1910 %>
```

While selecting the date for february it is showing 31 days instead of 28.. In the database it is adding 3days as if we select 31 st febrauary.. in the database it is showing 03 march.
how can i valid the date for calender ???
Thanks for suggestions in advance

Comment: You could add a custom validation method or even a custom validator to your model that uses DateTime.parse to parse the date of birth. If the date is 31/02/2016 then it will throw an ArgumentError that you can rescue and return false from. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370926/rails-built-in-datetime-validation

Answer (score 1):

Since the Rails helpers generate static HTML, you'll have to use javascript for this. Basically, you can listen for a `change` event on the month object, then use the builtin javascript `Date` to get the number of days for the month.

I've found that the following works for me. I didn't write it, however, so please fully test it yourself (Credit to https://gist.github.com/kpfefferle/1928544).

```
$(function () {
      railsMonthDates();
      $("select[id*=_2i], select[id*=_1i]").change( railsMonthDates );
    });

    function railsMonthDates() {
      $("select[id*=_2i]").each(function(){
        $monthSelect = $(this);
        $daySelect = $(this).siblings("select[id*=_3i]");
        $yearSelect = $(this).siblings("select[id*=_1i]");

        var year = parseInt($yearSelect.val());
        var month = parseInt($monthSelect.val());
        var days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

        var selectedDay = $daySelect.val()
        $daySelect.html('');
        for(var i=1; i<=days; i++) {
          $daySelect.append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
        }
        $daySelect.val(selectedDay);
      });
    }
```

Comment: it is still accepting the date of birth with feb 31 but in database it is showing 03 of march.....

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care for old browser support you could solve this by using the [`date_field`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-date_field) helper. It would play nice on mobile devices as well.

```ruby
date_field("user", "born_on", min: "2014-05-20")
# => <input id="user_born_on" name="user[born_on]" type="date" min="2014-05-20" />
```