# Automatically parsing date/time parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way to automatically parse string parameters representing dates in Rails? Or, some convention or clever way?

Doing the parsing manually by just doing `DateTime.parse(..)` in controllers, even if it's in a callback doesn't look very elegant.

There's also another case I'm unsure how to handle: If a date field in a model is nullable, I would like to return an error if the string I receive is not correct (say: the user submits `201/801/01`). This also has to be done in the controller and I don't find a clever way to verify that on the model as a validation.

Comment: Check if helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370926/rails-built-in-datetime-validation -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597328/how-do-i-validate-a-date-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ActiveRecord to back your model, your dates and time fields are automatically parsed before being inserted.

```
# migration
class CreateMydates < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :mydates do |t|
      t.date :birthday
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# irb
irb(main):003:0> m = Mydate.new(birthday: '2018-01-09')
=> #<Mydate id: nil, birthday: "2018-01-09", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):004:0> m.save
=> true
irb(main):005:0> m.reload
irb(main):006:0> m.birthday
=> Tue, 09 Jan 2018
```

So it comes down to validating the date format, which you can do manually with a regex, or you can call Date.parse and check for an exception:

```
class Mydate < ApplicationRecord
  validate :check_date_format

  def check_date_format
    begin
      Date.parse(birthday)
    rescue => e
      errors.add(:birthday, "Bad Date Format")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's what I meant by "parsing manually". I don't want to do that for each date field I have :)

Comment: ah I see you edited your question to include that. I'll add another answer

Comment: Yeah I didn't see automatically parsing was happening. Issue is that if the string is bad it will just return nil

Comment: You could add _before_type_cast to the variable name to get the invalid date and parse it manually. E.g. birthday_before_type_cast